# Hide group name in Word's ribbon

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I hide the group name in the Word's ribbon?

[image]

for example, it's the Clipboard, Font, Paragraph...in the picture

Comment: What version of Word?

Comment: it's the 2013 preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change or remove ribbon group labels:

1. Right click the the ribbon and choose `Customize the Ribbon...`.
2. In the right window, under `Main Tabs` expand the tab you want to modify.
   [image]
3. Select the `Group` (like Clipboard), then right click the name and choose `Rename`.
4. In the dialog box that comes up, modify or delete the `Display Name` and choose `OK`.
   [image]
5. Do this for each label you want to modify.

If you need to reset the ribbon back to default.

1. In the Customize the Ribbon window, click Reset.
2. Click Reset all customizations.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm…  I don’t see that on Word 2007.

Comment: @Scott: I think it was added in Office 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the group names does not make the ribbon shorter (which is what I wanted to do) - even if you remove all labels, you just get some empty space at the bottom of the ribbon...